# How to unroll an inner product calculation using julia macro?

Tags: macros, julia, mathematical-optimization

Using JuMP I want to make an objective function like this:

```
@objective(m, Max,  19*run[1] + 15*run[2] + 15*run[3])
```

... where 19, 15 and 15 are the utilities of activities, and `run[i]` is a binary JuMP variable describing if the activity should be run or not.

I want to make a macro that generates this objective, so that given a list of `utilities=(19, 15, 15)` instead of the above, I can write something like this:

```
@myObjective(m, Max, utilities, run)
```

and that will function like the objective I typed in above.

(the reasoning is that I don't want to use a quadratic objective, so I can't use a JuMP variable "utility" and let the objective be `sum(run[i]*utility[i])`. However since since I do know the utilities in advance, a macro can perhaps be written to write a nice linear objective function.  For three activities  a macro wouldn't help much, but in real problems there will be lots of activities, so it will be helpful.

I've been struggling for a while now and I'm not getting any traction, does anyone know how to easily fix this?

Also any other approaches to solving this problem not using macros would be useful :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unless `utilities` is a JuMP Variable, you can do
`@objective(m, Max, dot(utilities, run))`, that's not quadratic

Comment: This solves the problem.   ("import Base: dot" necessary, but that's of course a detail.)   Thank you ;)